# table margins in a list

Tags: css, html-table, html-lists, margins

In the following sample, I'd like to give a top-bottom margin to the table:

```css
li table {
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried a generic rule like: `li table { margin: 12px 0; }`
or even a specific style like `.breath { margin: 12px 0; }`, then added to `<table>` tag.

None worked.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this reading would help you nail what's your trouble here : https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `padding` for that `li` instead, to avoid the collapsing margins

Answer (score 0):

the default display of table is `display:table`, try using `inline-table`

```
li table {
  display: inline-table;
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```